# null reference exception when i delete item from sync realm database in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, realm, nullreferenceexception

[image]I got a null reference exception after I delete any item from the sync realm database .
the item is deleted from the database but it throws the exception and craches 
I don't know why it throws this exception or where is the null object .

but when I delete this line the exception disappears :
listView.ItemsSource = Employees;

PS : this exception appeared when I tried to sync the realm database online.

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Initialize();
        listView.ItemsSource = Employees;
    }    
private async Task Initialize()
    {
        _realm = await OpenRealm();
        Employees = _realm.All<Employee>();
        Entertainments= _realm.All<Entertainment>();
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Employees)));
    }

void OnDeleteClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try {
            var o = _realm.All<Employee>().FirstOrDefault(c => c.EmpId == 4);
            if (o != null)
                _realm.Write(() => { _realm.Remove(o); });
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Employees)));
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            string msg = exp.Message;
        }

    }
```

here is a screenshot of the exception

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/debugging?view=vsmac-2019

Comment: What is Employees? a List? Observablecollection?

Comment: @BrunoCaceiro    it is : IEnumerable<Employee>

Comment: There is your problem. Please, use a ObservableCollection<Employee> so you can dynamically add or remove items binded to the listview

Comment: that would not cause a null ref.  The stack trace of the exception object should tell you which line causes the exception

Comment: There is no screenshot of the exception btw

Comment: @Saamer I added a screenshot for the exception now , thank you .

Comment: @BrunoCaceiro THIS SOLVED THE EXCEPTION ! Thank youu . but the listview is not auto updated now !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Jason I have debugged but the debugger didn't tell me which line causes the exception , instead it jump to the exception in the screenshot here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9iOY.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> THIS SOLVED THE EXCEPTION ! Thank youu . but the listview is not auto updated now !

According to your code and description, you want to delete item form realm database, and update Listview. I find you use PropertyChanged to want to update Employees, but it doesn't work, because you delete item from realm database, don't change Employees, so it is not fired PropertyChanged  event.

```
 List<Employee> Employees = new List<Employee>();
    private async Task Initialize()
    {
        _realm = await OpenRealm();
        Employees = _realm.All<Employee>().ToList(); ;
        Entertainments = _realm.All<Entertainment>();

    }
    void OnDeleteClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var o = _realm.All<Employee>().FirstOrDefault(c => c.EmpId == 4);
            if (o != null)
                _realm.Write(() => { _realm.Remove(o); });
            Employees = _realm.All<Employee>().ToList();
            listView.ItemsSource = Employees;
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            string msg = exp.Message;
        }

    }
```

Helpful article for you:
https://dzone.com/articles/xamarinforms-working-with-realm-database